# android FATAL EXCEPTION: main when trying to start a new activity

Tags: java, android

I am writing an android app and am trying to start an activity from a button

The button calls the function startDb(), which is supposed to start the DB_manager activity.

The code and LogCat are shown below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void Main(){

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void startDb() {
        Intent activity1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DB_manager.class);
        startActivity(activity1);
        //finish();
    }
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not 

find a method startDb()(View) in the activity class com.example.quiz.MainActivity for 
onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'edit_db'

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3647)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: startDb() [class android.view.View]

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3640)

07-03 13:11:26.525: E/AndroidRuntime(19273):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
public void startDb() {
    Intent activity1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DB_manager.class);
    startActivity(activity1);
    //finish();
}
```

to

```
public void startDb(View v) {
    Intent activity1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DB_manager.class);
    startActivity(activity1);
    //finish();
}
```

I'm assuming you define your `OnClick` inxml. You need to have `View` as a parameter in your function header.

Also, it looks like you may be defining it in xml like

```
android:onClick="startDb()"
```

it should be

```
android:onClick="startDb"
```

No "()"

[From the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

> In order for this to work, the method must be public and accept a View as its only parameter. For example:

Comment: @Raghunandan  Thanks, and 1 to you. I didn't notice the `public void Main()` because I was looking at the function...good catch!

Answer (score 1):

If you define onClick attribute for button in xml

```
   public void startDb(View v) {
    Intent activity1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DB_manager.class);
    startActivity(activity1);
    //finish();
     }
```

You can also remove this

```
    public void Main(){

    }
```